El formato de fecha no me deja guardar información desde mi form.py en pythonanywhere
tengo una duda respecto a las fechas, resulta que por alguna extraña razón funciona de maravilla en local y cuando lo subo a pythonanywhere no. El problema se debe a una situación con el formato de fecha con mis formularios; estoy usando datepicker y TempusDominus.
Cambié el formato de la fecha para que quede 2024/05/05 (yyyy/mm/dd) porque el de datepicker me daba dd/mm/yyyy y mandaba un "invalid date", ahora por lo menos cuando elijo la fecha ya aparece como yyyy/mm/dd, sólo que al guardar los datos aparece otro error similar al anterior, que dice: "Introduzca una fecha válida" y es que al verificar el input me cambia el formato a dd/mm/yyyy cosa que no quiero y no entiendo porque me lo vuelve a colocar como dd/mm/yyyy, alguna idea?
form.py
'fecha_emision': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
#'valor': datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
'required': True}),
'fecha_inicio': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
#'valor': datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
'required': True}),
'fecha_termino': forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control',
#'valor': datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"),
'required': True}),``` 

base.html
    var fechaEmisionPicker = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById("fecha_emision"), {
        display: {
            viewMode: "calendar",
            components: {
                decades: true,
                year: true,
                month: true,
                date: true,
                hours: false,
                minutes: false,
                seconds: false
            }
        }
    });
    fechaEmisionPicker.dates.formatInput = function(date) {
        return moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
    };

settings.py
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'es_MX.UTF-8')
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es'
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Mexico_City'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-Mx'

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = [
'%Y-%m-%d',
'%d/%m/%Y',
'%m/%d/%Y',
'%Y/%m/%d',
]``` 

